What to do? resizefs2 processing <1000K/s at "updating inode references"
I'm trying on resizing an ext4 partition using gparted on Ubuntu 22.04.  I'm shrinking 4TB to ~3TB with ~1.5TB of the drive filled.  It's now been working on this task for >24hr, but is still progressing, just painfully slow. To be exact, iotop shows resize2fs with a disk read of ~400K/s (yes K) and disk write of ~200K/sec.  In addition, this is the main load according to iotop.
Is there any reasonable recourse I can take or things to check beyond it not being mounted (which it isn't)?

If you are able to stop this process without endangering your filesystem, I recommend to do that. Then you may use resize2fs -M /dev/DEVICE on the unmounted filesystem. This will shrink the filesystem to its minimum size. (Minimum size to be able to allocate all its files.) Then you are able to adjust the partition table, as you desire, but make sure the partition is still bigger than the filesystem. Then you can enlarge the filesystem with resize2fs /dev/DEVICE towards the new boundaries of the partition.
If the CLI commands work also as slow as gparted, you have probably an hardware failure. So I recommend to copy the filesystem/files to another drive.

Thanks! I will try those steps after I stop the process, but I guess my question is what's the best way to stop this process without endangering" the filesystem?  $ kill <PID> or is there a better option?

Apparently it's best to cancel such an operation from within GParted, rather than using kill on the CLI, due the possibility it will be able to recover from the error and reset the partition table to the pre-modification state.  So, that's what I did (Cancel -> Wait 5 sec -> Cross fingers -> Click Force Cancel') and there were no apparent problems and I appear to have been able to resize the drive using Gparted on the second attempt.
